# Global View visible in all .xib ViewControllers

Tags: swift, view, global, xib

I'm trying to create a "Global View" maybe it goes into AppDelegate, but I'm not sure. I would like my View to always be visible, no matter what ViewController .xib you are on in the app.

For now I have inserted the View in the first ViewController .xib but when I navigate in the other ViewControllers the View disappears.

This is the code:

```
import UIKit

class MonitoringViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForTab: UIView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

    
    
    @IBAction func buttonTab1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonTab2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.navigateToAlertViewController()
        
        let alert = AlertViewController(nibName: "AlertViewController", bundle: nil)
        contentView.addSubview(alert.view)
        alert.didMove(toParent: self)

    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTab3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Create global view controller as root view controller. Put yours global view and  navigation controller in it.

Comment: Cy-4AH i don't understand, can you explain yourself better please?